# How to run doxygen through NSIS installer?

Tags: svn, doxygen, nsis

I have a set of files/folders/projects in an .svn folder. I am using an NSIS script to take some of the build files and bring them to a completely separate directory. The NSIS script generates a .exe that the user will run so the user will get a local version of the build files. That part is rather straightforward in NSIS.

The complication for me is I have to (am required to) run Doxygen at the time the user runs the NSIS file so that the user get the most updated documentation of the code inside. Obviously, the code and build files are very fluid. I know I can run Doxygen through the command line with the Doxyfiles in the appropriate directories. (i.e doxygen ). This will generate the .chm file i need to push to the user's machine. Any clues on how to run this? Do I need to bring in a plug in???

I apologize is this is vague or inane. I'm not a programmer. That may be obvious.

Comment: What do you mean by "user runs the NSIS file"? Are you talking about a .nsi script or the generated .exe?

Comment: I was trying to say that the user will run the .exe that the .nsi script generates.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear to me when you want to run Doxygen but NSIS can execute things both at compile-time (the machine you are running makensis on) and at run-time (the end-users machine):

```
Section "CompileTime"
!system '"Doxygen" -foo -bar -out "baz.chm"'
SetOutPath "$InstDir\Docs"
File "baz.chm"
SectionEnd
```

or

```
Section "RunTime"
CreateDirectory "$InstDir\Docs"
ExecWait '"Doxygen" -foo -bar -out "$InstDir\Docs\baz.chm"'
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try to implement the runtime version.  My remaining question is this... Say I have the installer.exe in a folder. I want to generate new .chm files for code contained in folder\code1\... and folder\code2\... Basically, I'm just running down through folders running Doxygen. Any tips on how to perform? It seems simple, but I'm a bit confused. 

To check as well... The format of the .chm will be dependent upon the doxyfile in the folder doxygen is run, correct?

Comment: Also, can you explain your usage of -foo -bar -out? Is that a doxygen thing?

Comment: I figured it was something improvisational... but what are those for anyway? I suppose I dont understand where any of that syntax is documented (nor what a 'switch' is in this context)

Comment: Try running `doxygen --help`, it should show all the available options (switches). I don't know if it has a -out option or some other way of specifying the name of the .chm. Maybe it is based on the input name but I just made something up in my example, sorry for the confusion. See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command-line_option